# How can I get posts from a facebook page using the graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created a meta app using the email address associated with the base facebook account that created the page I am trying to get the posts from. In the Graph API Explorer I have selected my meta app and "user token". When I add the page ID to the query string field and click submit I get the error:"(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature."

But I don't see 'pages_read_engagement' in the list of permissions to choose from. Do I need to apply for "page public content access"?
Do I need to use a page token?
When I try to select "Page Access Token" as the token type I get a pop up saying "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."